# GitLab - Can I enable search by code or commits across all projects of GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

When I select all projects, I cannot search by commits or code.
Can I enable search by code or commits across all projects?

[image: Any project]
[image: Select project]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only do this across an entire instance for self-managed GitLab instances OR searching across repositories within a single organization/group in GitLab.com

For example, you can [search across all of the `gitlab-org` group](https://gitlab.com/search?group_id=9970&repository_ref=main&scope=blobs&search=runner&snippets=false) or any other group/namespace you have access to.

[image: GitLab Group Search]

Currently, GitLab has not enabled global code search on `gitlab.com`. However, self-hosted GitLab Premium and Ultimate customers can leverage the [advanced search feature](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/search/advanced_search.html) and enable global code search for a self-managed instance with Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

That might be because a true global code search does not seem to be implemented yet, as illustrated by [issue 556](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/556#note_733943390) or [issue 14597](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/14597#note_733943277).

Which is why there are alternatives like [`phillipj/gitlab-search`](https://github.com/phillipj/gitlab-search) (but only to search for contents across all *your* GitLab repositories)